# Goldbach Conjecture Verify up to N in Python

Tags: python

I seem to have created an infinite loop in my python code. My aim was to create a function 'check' which uses my previous 'goldbach' function to confirm that every even number greater than 4 and up to the inputted N comply with the Goldbach Conjecture (a pretty pointless procedure, I know, but it's for my assignment). I know that my 'goldbach' function is working well and produces a pair of primes that sum to N for 'good' inputs and (0,0) for 'bad' inputs. I want my check function to return True for all even inputs greater than 4 (as these comply with the conjecture), and False for any odd inputs. However, my code won't run when I try my check function in the console so something has gone wrong - any ideas what it is?

```
def goldbach(N):
    x, y = 0, 0
    result = 0
    if N % 2 == 0:
        prime = odd_primes(N)
        while result != N:
            for i in range(len(prime)):
                if result == N: break
                x = prime[i]
                for j in range(len(prime)):
                    y = prime[j]
                    result = x + y
                    if result == N: break 
    return x, y 

def check(N):
    for n in range(4, N+1):
        if n % 2 ==0:
            g = goldbach(n)
            if g == (0,0):
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

Comment: What do you mean "it won't run"? What happens when you try?

Comment: can you provide `odd_primes` function?

Comment: Returning from a function ends the loop. So `check` just checks `4`, not all the numbers in the range.

Comment: Do you want to test all the numbers in the range, and return `True` at the end if all the even `n` return non-zero results and all the old `n` return `(0, 0)`?

Comment: @Tim I press Run and then it freezes as if I'm trying to run an infinite loop. I then have to open a new console to do anything else.

Comment: @Barmar I want to look at all even numbers in the range(4, N+1) and put them through the goldbach function, then if all of those return non (0, 0) outputs, return 'True' or, if not, 'False'. Hope that makes more sense!

Comment: There's no infinite loop in `check()`. There must be a problem with the loop in `goldbach()`.

Comment: It will go into an infinite loop if `result` is never equal to `N`. Maybe it should be `while result < N:`

Comment: I suggest you add some `print` statements to `goldbach()` to see what's happening there.

Comment: Since the conjecture is known to be true up to 400,000,000,000,000, maybe the problem is with `odd_primes()`. If it's not returning all primes, you could get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a replacement for your function `odd_primes(N)`, to return a list of all the primes less than or equal to N (having 2 in the there doesn't seem to make a difference).  Your `check()` function seems to check all integers between 4 and N inclusive, and return `False` if it finds something for which no Goldbach sum was found.  However, as somebody else pointed out, it also immediately returns `True` once it finds a pair.  So what happens when you run `check()` is that starts with the number 4, finds that its Goldbach pair is (2,2), then immediately quits the function by returning `True`, ignoring any other values between 4 and N.

When I replace the `return True` with a `print` statement and just add a `return True after the entire loop:

```
def check(N):
    for n in range(4, N+1):
        if n % 2 ==0:
            g = goldbach(n)
            if g == (0,0):
                print("No sum found for %d !" % n)
                return False
            else:
                print("%d is equal to %d + %d" % (n, g[0], g[1]))
    return True
```

and then run `check(20)` for example, I get:

```
4 is equal to 2 + 2
6 is equal to 3 + 3
8 is equal to 3 + 5
10 is equal to 3 + 7
12 is equal to 5 + 7
14 is equal to 3 + 11
16 is equal to 3 + 13
18 is equal to 5 + 13
20 is equal to 3 + 17
```

By the way, if you just want to know whether a given even number can be written as the sum of two primes but you don't care what the actual pair of primes is, you could do something like this:

```
def goldbach(N):
    if N % 2 == 0:
        primes = odd_primes(N)
        # Generate a list of all the i+j sums where j >= i (skipping
        # most duplicates this way), and see if N is among the sums.
        sums = [i + j for i in primes for j in primes[primes.index(i):]]
        return(N in sums)
    else:
        print("N must be even.")
        return(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning immediately after checking the first item in the range. You need to return `False` as soon as you encounter an item that doesn't match expectations, and return `True` at the end if all of them match expectations.

If you only want to look at even numbers, use a stride of `2` in the `range()` function rather than testing each number to see if it's even or odd.

```
def check(N):
    for n in range(4, N+1, 2):
        if goldbach(n) == (0, 0):
            return False
    return True
```

You don't need the `while` loop in `goldbach()`. The two `for` loops test all combinations of primes. If they don't find a matching pair, there's no reason to restart them.

You can also simplify and optimize your loops. The inner loop only needs to test primes starting from `x`, because pairs of primes where `y < x` would have already been tested in an earlier iteration of `x`.

```
def goldbach(N):
    if N % 2 == 0:
        prime = odd_primes(N)
        for i, x in enumerate(prime):
            for y in prime[i:]:
                if x + y == N:
                    return x, y 
    return 0, 0
```

However, I think your code should still work, which suggests that the problem is actually that `odd_primes()` isn't returning all primes up to `N`.

Comment: that makes sense but it still won't run when I try to apply the check function in the console

Comment: Looping over a range can't be infinite. The problem must be with the `while` loop in `goldback()`.